# How can I add a stable marker (solid circle on image)? Which will be at the same position on the next frame of the camera?

Tags: android, ios, opencv, camera

I am thinking to add markers on images taken from camera output similar to what the *[Google PhotoScan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Photos#History)* application does. As I can see the *Google PhotoScan* app adds four solid circle on an image which is overlayed and then moves the center hollow circle towards all four solid circles and capture the four images. It stitches them together to create a high-quality image.

Here are screenshots for reference (the *solid* dots you can see are always there even on the same color background. *Even* if you move the camera around and back to initial position, they will display at the same position):

The *solid* dots you can see are always there, even on the same color background. *Even* if you move the camera around and back to the initial position, they will display at the same position:

[image]

I am very curious: How are they able to stable those four solid circles? Are they using an optical flow algorithm? Or an motion sensors? I tested the application on a white colour or the same colour background those dots stay stable.

I implemented this functionality using an optical flow algorithm ([Lucas–Kanade method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method) in OpenCV). But they are not stable when I am using them on the same colour background or on a white colour background (basically, in the Lucas–Kanade algorithm, if it does not find the feature, it tries to shift that point). Here is the screenshot for my implementation:

[image]

Comment: maybe using additional sensors of the camera like compass and gyros?

Comment: Hi @Micka...Thanks for your reply...I tried using the gyro and accelerometer  in iOS...but it didn't track the small movements...I thought to use batch tracking instead of single point using https://www.gnebehay.com/tld/    TLD but it is very slow to work on iPhone......is there any way I could implement Lucas-Kanade algorithm to track batch of points at single place....

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's sensor-based. There is no way to achieve the result they did with Optical Flow or - for that matter - any image-processing algorithms. You just can't guarantee that it will work exactly the same in all conditions.

Comment: I tested this on completely black and white background it did not work I guess they are not using any sensors here.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a computer vision problem.

I really appreciate [Jeek Axio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905163/how-can-i-add-a-stable-marker-solid-circle-on-image-which-will-be-at-the-same/43222451#43222451). You can use multiple sensors on an Android device as 'prime' factors in a computer vision problem.

However, as of state-of-the-art computer vision methods, it's possible to solve this tracking problem with a very good accuracy.

You may use [EKLT](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_feature_tracking_analysis), [PointTrack](https://github.com/detectRecog/PointTrack) methods to track the feature points.

There's also a full-featured toolbox called [FTK](https://github.com/hguo/ftk).

Comment: Jeek Axio's answer was the result of blatant [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) (*"1. Copying of another person's ideas, text or other creative work, and presenting it as one's own, especially without permission; plagiarizing. 2. Text or other work resulting from this act. The novel was awash in plagiarism, with entire passages lifted verbatim."*).